# finding radius of convergence involving limits

Tags: analysis

given $\displaystyle \sum_{n=2}^\infty a_nx^n$ is a power series find the radius of convergence when

a) $lim_{n\to\infty}a_n/\log(n) = 1$

my attempt,

using ratio test $|\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|x|| = |x|\left|\dfrac{\log(n+1)}{\log(n)}\right |\left |\dfrac{\frac{a_{n+1}}{\log(n+1)}}{\frac{a_n}{\log(n)}}\right | \to |x|$ so $R = 1$. Is this correct? if so, how can I show that $\left|\dfrac{\log(n+1)}{\log(n)}\right | \to 1$? (i've tried using definition of convergence of a sequence.

b) $n^3 < |a_n| < n^4$

I tried a similar approach here;

$1/n^4 < 1/|a_n| < 1/n^3$

$\dfrac{(n+1)^3}{n^4}<\dfrac{|a_{n+1}|}{n^4} < \dfrac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|} < \dfrac{|a_{n+1}|}{n^3} < \dfrac{(n+1)^4}{n^3}$ however I can't use the comparison test here and not sure where to go from here...

any help please

Comment: $\log (n+1) = \log \left(n\left(1+\frac1n\right)\right) = \log n + \log \left(1+\frac1n\right)$

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you - do you have any tips for part b)?

Comment: Do you know the root test? That's simpler in that case.

Comment: @DanielFischer The general root test or the root test given in the answer below? (I know of the former, which I will try tomorrow morning, not the latter).

Comment: (The one given in the answer is the ratio test.) Either works well, whether you take $\sqrt[n]{\lvert a_n\rvert}$ or $\sqrt[n]{\lvert a_nx^n\rvert}$, the difference is just a constant factor of $\lvert x\rvert$, so you can easily translate from one to the other.

Answer (score 0):

The root test for the power series
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n,
$$
is applied as follows:

If $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}\right|=r\in[0,\infty]$,
then the radius of convergence of the power series above is $r$ - Note that $x$ is not used in the ratio.

So, in our case
$$
\left|\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}\right|=\frac{\log n}{\log(n+1)}\left|\frac{\frac{a_n}{\log n}}{\frac{a_{n+1}}{\log(n+1)}}\right|\to 1\cdot\frac{1}{1}=1,
$$
and hence the radius of convergence is equal to $1$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - I have yet to cover this type of root test specifically for power series - I have just the general root and ratio test.